# Password validation with javascript and regex doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, forms

I tried to validate the password with a regex function in javascript. I set the button disabled on default and when the password is valid, I want to enable the button.

The validation doesn't work.

Here you can see the javascript code:

```
function validPW() {
if (isValid("passwort",document.getElementById("passwordRegistrationID").value)) {
    document.getElementById('passwordRegistrationID').disabled=false;
}

function isValid (type, toValidate){
switch (type){
    case "grossbuchstabeVorhanden" :
        var grossbuchstabe = /[A-Z]+/;
        return grossbuchstabe.test (toValidate);
        break;
    case "kleinbuchstabenVorhanden" :
        var kleinbuchstabe = /[a-z]+/;
        return kleinbuchstabe.test (toValidate);
    case "zahlenVorhanden" :
        var zahlen = /[0-9]+/;
        return zahlen.test (toValidate);
    case "sonderzeichenVorhanden" :
        var sonderzeichen = /[?!$%&/=<>_]+/;
        return sonderzeichen.test (toValidate);
    case "laengeRjichtig" :
        var laenge =/.{9,}/;
        return laenge.test (toValidate);
    case "passwort":
        return isValid("grossbuchstabeVorhanden",toValidate) && isValid("kleinbuchstabenVorhanden",toValidate)
            && isValid("zahlenVorhanden",toValidate) && isValid("sonderzeichenVorhanden",toValidate)
            && isValid("laengeRjichtig",toValidate)
}
```

Here is the html form

```
<form role="form" action="/user/doRegistration" method="post" class="login-form">
    <div class="form-group" id="usernameRegistrationDiv">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-usernameRegistration">Username</label>
        <input type="email" name="form-usernameRegistration" required="required" placeholder="Username..." class="form-usernameRegistration form-control"
            id="form-usernameRegistration">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="passwordRegistrationDiv">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-passwordRegistration">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="form-passwordRegistration" required="required" placeholder="Password..." class="form-passwordRegistration form-control"
            id="passwordRegistrationID" oninput="validPW();">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-password-registration">Password repeat</label>
        <input type="password" name="form-password-registration" required="required" placeholder="Password repeat..." class="form-password-registration form-control"
            id="form-password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="buttonRegistration" class="btn" disabled> Sign up!</button>
</form>
```

Error Message:

```
registration:97 Uncaught ReferenceError: validPW is not defined
```

Comment: And what is your error? Your validation works and your disable = false works

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation works perfectly in my tests, although the function you have posted is missing 2 closing braces, so it is technically not valid JavaScript, though I assume the braces are present in your local copy. Here's what it should be:

```js
    function validPW() {
if (isValid("passwort",document.getElementById("passwordRegistrationID").value)) {
    document.getElementById('passwordRegistrationID').disabled=false;
}

function isValid (type, toValidate){
switch (type){
    case "grossbuchstabeVorhanden" :
        var grossbuchstabe = /[A-Z]+/;
        return grossbuchstabe.test (toValidate);
        break;
    case "kleinbuchstabenVorhanden" :
        var kleinbuchstabe = /[a-z]+/;
        return kleinbuchstabe.test (toValidate);
    case "zahlenVorhanden" :
        var zahlen = /[0-9]+/;
        return zahlen.test (toValidate);
    case "sonderzeichenVorhanden" :
        var sonderzeichen = /[?!$%&/=<>_]+/;
        return sonderzeichen.test (toValidate);
    case "laengeRjichtig" :
        var laenge =/.{9,}/;
        return laenge.test (toValidate);
    case "passwort":
        return isValid("grossbuchstabeVorhanden",toValidate) && isValid("kleinbuchstabenVorhanden",toValidate)
            && isValid("zahlenVorhanden",toValidate) && isValid("sonderzeichenVorhanden",toValidate)
            && isValid("laengeRjichtig",toValidate)
}
}
}
```

Otherwise, I couldn't find any issues whilst doing a quick test with a valid and and invalid password.

Comment: shouldnt be the last closing backet be for validPW

Comment: Depends on the original intention - it works  both ways, because "isValid" could either be a nested function, or a global function in its own right.

Comment: Also, I meant to say that the ```debugger``` statement is your friend when testing. Insert it anywhere into your code, and even if you are running your code directly in the browser JS console, the debugger will stop at this point so you can see what's going on in your code. Just remember to remove the statement before putting your code live.

Comment: In my test, the button is enabled, even if I enter a valid password. I got an error message in the console.

Comment: This indicates  that the "validPW" function is not defined at the point where it is called. The most obvious cause of this is a syntax error in the function definition, and as I indicated previously, it seems there are some missing closing braces in your code (`}`). Notice that in the validPW function, you close off your `if` statement with a closing brace, but not your `validPW` function.